# Using stored procedure in Entity Framework with input parameters - how to use in Linq query?

Tags: visual-studio, linq, stored-procedures

I do not know how to use my stored procedure in Visual Studio in a linq query. I want to call my stored procedure and pass it my parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ServiceEntities DBContext= new ServiceEntities();
        var AGCode = 5600;
        var ToDate = "2020/12/07";
        var MySp=(from  n in dbo.SP_Ag_DebitPayState(ToDate , AGCode) 
                 select n).ToList();
```

I have find this and it work!